# Adding column and adding COUNT data

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

I'm supposed to take count from a column of one table and a make a new column in another table with the count.

Add to a relational table DAY CARE CENTER information about the total number of enrolments handled by each day care center. Note, that if a day care center handled no enrolment then for such day care center the total number of enrollment must be set to zero. Enforce the appropriate consistency constraints on a relational table DAY CARE CENTER.

I'm not getting any proper code for this at all. I've tried multiple variations, but nothing works. The number of enrolments I get from another table called DAY_CARE_ENROLMENT.

I'm new to sql so please excuse my stupid mistakes. Can someone help?

```
ALTER TABLE DAY_CARE_CENTER  
ADD totalEnrol INTEGER(1) DEFAULT '0';

UPDATE DAY_CARE_CENTER
SET totalEnrol = COUNT(enrolStartDate)
WHERE centerID IN (SELECT centerID FROM DAY_CARE_ENROLMENT
WHERE DAY_CARE_CENTER.centerID=DAY_CARE_ENROLMENT.centerID);
```

Comment: If you want to use data from another table you must do a full `SELECT`, something like `UPDATE tbl SET col  = (SELECT COUNT(enrolStartDate) FROM tbl WHERE [...] )`

Comment: `INTEGER(1)` ? what is your goal with that as adding the `(1)` is more or less useless without [zerofill](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html) option.. If your goal is to limit the number and storage size you most likely should use a `TINYINT` which is a 1 byte storage vs `INTEGER(1)` which is always 4 bytes. See [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)..

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to aggregate before attempting the `UPDATE`.  That is, aggregate in a subquery and `JOIN` that into the table being updated:

```
UPDATE DAY_CARE_CENTER dcc JOIN
       (SELECT dce.centerID, COUNT(*) as cnt
        FROM DAY_CARE_ENROLMENT dce
        GROUP BY dce.centerID
       ) dce
       ON dcc.centerID = dce.centerID
    SET totalEnrol = cnt;
```

This is probably a bad approach.  The count will be out-of-date the next time a row in `DAY_CARE_ENROLMENT` changes.  You will need to either re-run the `UPDATE` or start using `insert`/`update`/`delete` triggers.

It is better to calculate such values on-the-fly.  Only summarize them when you need to for performance reasons.